# Convert array of char[] to byte[] and vice versa? C++

Tags: c++, char

What is the best way to convert an array of chars to bytes and vice versa?

Solution:

```
void CharToByte(char* chars, byte* bytes, unsigned int count){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        bytes[i] = (byte)chars[i];
}

void ByteToChar(byte* bytes, char* chars, unsigned int count){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         chars[i] = (char)bytes[i];
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The type char is one of the few types that has a size guaranteed by the ANSI standard and that size is 1 byte.  As far as I know C does not directly define the type byte.  However it would be just short of insane to have a type named byte which is not in fact a byte in size.  Therefore a simple cast should do the trick.

Comment: @soulmerge yes but I'm not sure it's officially a part of the standard.

Answer (score 7):

There is no byte type in C++, and according to the Standard:

Edit:

1.7:

> A byte is at least large enough to
>   contain any member of the basic
>   execution character set and is
>   composed of a contiguous sequence of
>   bits, the number of which is
>   implementation-defined.

5.3.3:

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and
>   sizeof(unsigned char) are 1; the
>   result of sizeof applied to any other
>   fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined.

Comment: Actually, I believe a char is defined to be exactly 1 byte (but at least 8 bits). At least, sizeof(char) is defined to be 1.

Comment: @Chris: According to 1.7 in the standard, a byte is defined as "at least large enough to hold any member of the basic execution character set", but this may involve an implementation-defined number of bits.  The size of char is always exactly 1 such "byte."

Comment: This is untrue as there is now a std::byte in c++17.

Answer (score 4):

There is no byte type in C++.  You could typedef 'unsigned char' to 'byte' if that makes it nicer.  Really thats all a byte is in C++ - an unsigned char.  Aside from that, yes I would cast...  but this cast is better:

```
unsigned_char_arr[i]= static_cast<unsigned char>(char_arr[i]);
```

or... just use the char array and cast it when it needs to be interpreted as an unsigned char...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `static_cast<unsigned char>` will result in a compile failure. For some reason, C++ requires a `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>` or  `reinterpret_cast<byte>`. I've never really understood why since they are the same width and only the potential sign changes depending on the bit pattern.

Comment: For larger files, also consider the performance impact of a few million calls of `reinterpret_cast<byte>`, or equivalent.

Comment: how to convert "unsigned char *" to python bytes by use pybind11?

Answer (score 1):

In almost every C++ implementation you'll come across, a `char` is exactly <s>a `byte`</s> an octet.  This is not guaranteed by the C++ standard, but it's practically always the case.  A `char` is always *at least* 8 bits large, and the exact number of bits is given by the preprocessor constant `CHAR_BIT`.  Also, the `sizeof()` operator tells you the size of an object/type in terms of the number of `char`s, not the number of <s>bytes</s> octets, so if you were on some weird system with a 16-bit `char` and a 32-bit `int`, then `sizeof(int)` would be 2, not 4.

**EDIT:** Replaced byte by octet.  A `char` is guaranteed to be a byte by the C standard, but a byte is not guaranteed to be an octet, which is exactly 8 bits.  If you've ever read any French technical literature, they always use 'octet' instead of 'byte', and they have kilooctets (KO), megaoctets (MO), etc. instead of kilbytes and megabytes.

Comment: "This is not guaranteed by the C++ standard..." Really? I'm pretty sure it's guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: In C++ we get the number of bits in a char with std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits, defined in <limits>.

Comment: @Adam, the size of char is guaranteed by the standard back to ANSI 89.  It's one of the very few types they ever bothered to give a concrete size to.