# Send double over local UNIX sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I'm trying to set up a UNIX socket server/client between two C++ programs, following [Beejs Guide to UNIX IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html), however the sample code only demonstrates sending and receiving char arrays. I've already seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168829/c-sockets-send-recv-buffer-type) some people claiming the best option is to convert the double value to a char, however as I want to pass values several times in a second, I would like to avoid this type of conversion. Right now I'm trying to pass the pointer to a certain double, but I don't know how to get the value on the other side. In the socket client I am doing:

```
...
double number = 453.23;
send(s, &number, sizeof(number), 0);
```

but I have the feeling this is not the right approach.

Comment: Would this be for a cross-platform app? remember that there might be differences on endianness  between different OSs

Comment: No, it is just a Linux program, to be run on the same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both sides have the same representation for `double`s (including endianness), on the other side of the socket you can do substantially the same thing:

```
double number;
recv(s, &number, sizeof(number), 0);
```

(of course assuming that either you are only transmitting `double`s or you have some kind of protocol and at this point of the program you are sure the sender has sent your `double`)

If endianness is not guaranteed then you have to decide an endianness for your transmission and swap the bytes appropriately; finally, if not even the basic representation of FP types is guaranteed, your best bet may be just writing the numbers as text, doing the relevant `sscanf`/`sprintf`.

Comment: What exactly is *endianess*? I'm sure that the values that I am sending `doubles`, it is pretty much hardcoded into the program. On the other hand, would this same approach work when using data structures other that a simple `double`? I'm getting a segmentation fault when passing a `VectorXd` object from Eigen Libraries this way.

Comment: @joaocandre: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness; if you are passing data only on the same machine or between machines on the same architecture (e.g. x86 & co.) you don't have to worry about it. For the rest, this approach works only with POD ("Plain Old Data") types, for non-POD classes you have to serialize them in some way and re-build them on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

1. If "several times a second" is really just "several" (i. e. a few dozen or even a few hundred or a few thousand) times a second, then converting to a char array should not have a serious impact on performance.
2. But you don't need this kind of conversion anyway. If you are using IPC, then it's highly probable that the two programs run physically on the very same machine - if you send raw memory representation of scalar data, it will be interpreted in the same manner on the receiver end (this does not hold for pointers of course). Until you don't want to be cross-platform (in the sense that you don't want to exchange data between two different architectures), don't worry about proper serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Information transmitted over sockets does not have Data types as you understand them in programming languages.
Char arrays are essentially byte arrays (depends on the C standard).
See [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876213/convert-array-of-char-to-byte-and-vice-versa-c)

You can either transmit the double you have, and then try to cast from bytes received, or you can somehow serialize it, and then deserialize.
Several times a second means nothing, if you app crashes or develops undefined behavior due to poor implementations or assumptions.

Be careful to do alot of error checking when you send/receive data over sockets, as assumptions are the mother of all ...

IMHO encapsulate your data in a JSON, XML or other form, so that both parties know exactly what is being transmitted.

EDIT: if you are using an IPC, you might as well setup a shared memory?

Comment: I'm taking my first steps on Unix IPC right now, just to share data between two processes on the same machine. Shared memory seems like it would require a more complex implementation, what would the advantages of such an approach?

Comment: Its really easy and simple. Essentially the OS allocates a memory file to which both processes can write and read. No sockets, pipes, etc. I believe it is the fastest way to communicate within processes, but requires synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some socket programs which send binary values: integers and doubles, but in order to do that, you must be certain that both machines (server and client) are binary compatible (byte order). Make sure that in both machines the size of a double (sizeof(double)) are the same, 8 bytes. This is the case for Intel machines and Tablets Android they are the same in C#, C++, Java and Delphi. Also I do binary transfer between tablets (Android and Java) to a program in Windows XP and 7 written in C# and it works.

Remember that it won't be portable and test should be made before porting to other platforms.

I'll give you some examples:

C++

```
// Sender
Send(socket, &MyDouble, sizeof(MyDouble), 0);

// Reader
Recv(socket, &MyDouble, sizefof(MyDouble), 0);
```

Java:

```
// Sender
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8);
buff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // To Intel machines
buff.putDouble(MyDouble);
Socket.getOutputStream().write(buff.array(), 0, 8);

// Reader 
byte[] data new byte[8];
Socket.getInputStream().read (data, 0, 8);
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
buff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // From Intel machines
MyDouble = buff.getDouble();
```