# how to parse raw data to literal types

Tags: c++

I'm getting the data as a pointer to bytes array. I know that it 's constructed as a three section and I have to initialize the variable of following types:

1. a flag of current block status

   ```
   enum class data_state {
       not_received, 
       file_name_only, 
       received,       
       eof
   };
   ```
2. The size of third section with real data

   ```
   unsigned long data_size;
   ```
3. The data

   ```
   unsigned char* data;
   ```

What is right way to parse raw data as byte array into variables of the types above?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Convert array of char[] to byte[] and vice versa? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876213/convert-array-of-char-to-byte-and-vice-versa-c)

```
void ByteToChar(byte* bytes, char* chars, unsigned int count){
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     chars[i] = (char)bytes[i];
}
```

This method is using simple type casting to convert from a byte to a char. Therefore, to determine the size of the third step, you must know the size of the byte array.

Comment: sorry , probably my question was unclear, so my question is - how to initialize some type by getting a few bytes from byte array in case of I know offset and count of the bytes?                      something like data_state ds = static_cast<data_state>(get_bytes(data, offset, bytes_count));